# Concatenate files

Tags: linux, bash, cat

When I try to concatenate multiple files using a loop, it concatenates the first line of the succeeding file with the last line of the preceding file. 
For e.g I have the following two files:

```
File1   File2   
1.234    12.11
2.345    0.00
11.567   4.56
7.890    2.34
```

I use the following script

```
for i in File1 File2
do 
      cat $i &
done >> tmp.txt
```

and here is how `tmp.txt` looks like

```
1.234    
2.345    
11.567   
7.890 12.11
0.00
4.56
2.34
```

This is just one example and it can be solved in vi by using "Enter" key but I have around 100s of these files and each files have nearly 50 lines.

Comment: Why are you running `cat` in the background in the loop?

Comment: I tried without running in background. But didnt work.

Comment: Define "didn't work"? Because it should have worked just fine. Did it hang? That would happen if you managed to get an empty string into `$i` since you didn't quote the expansion and ended up running `cat` which reads from standard input.

Comment: @EtanReisner : When I tried without "&", I still got the same result.

Comment: That sounds like the last line of File1 is incomplete, i.e. it lacks a newline terminator. How did you create File1?

Comment: I may be getting your question wrong but why don't you simply use `cat File1 >> File2` ?

Comment: @melpomene: I didn't get it. You mean the last line should have an empty space ? In that case I will have to modify all of these 100 files.

Comment: Yeah, if that's consistent without the backgrounding (which is entirely unnecessary and going to cause ordering/data problems for larger files) then the files almost certainly just do not have trailing newlines. This is common for files coming from Windows/etc.

Comment: No, the last line needs to end with a newline. DOS/Windows type files often don't because `\r\n` is a line-separator in that universe as opposed to `\n` being a line **terminator** in the Unix universe.

Comment: @PedroLobito: I have more than two files. I have used two files just for the example. Basically I am concatenating 100s of these files.

Comment: Into the same temp.txt ?

Comment: check my answer it may help  you.

Comment: You need to make sure that each file ends in a newline. Otherwise you get the "7.890 12.11" output which I don't think you intend.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop here. You can concatenate the files directly in one shot:

```
cat File1 File2 >> tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below will loop all `.txt` files on the current `dir` and concatenate them into `temp.out`

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=./*.txt
for f in $FILES
do
  cat $f >> temp.out
done
```

---

**NOTE:**

I've tested the script with the examples you've provided and it works as intended.

```
1.234
2.345
11.567
7.890
12.11
0.00
4.56
2.34
```

Comment: If this is run twice, then temp.out will have two runs. Delete temp.out first.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito : I have tried this but it didn't work. Still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

As others have established, your problem is caused by line endings. I would suggest running your files through awk to normalise them:

```
awk '{ sub(/\r$/, ""); print }' File1 File2 > tmp.txt
```

This removes the carriage return (`\r`, part of the Windows-style line ending) from the end of each record, if present. `print` appends the output record separator (`ORS`, a newline `\n` on Linux) to each line.

Note that there is absolutely no need for a loop here. Multiple files can be passed as arguments to awk (or cat for that matter, in fact that's exactly what the point of cat is).

Testing it out, using some files with Windows-style line endings and no newline at the end of each file:

```
$ cat file1 file2
1.234
2.345
11.567
7.89012.11
0.00
4.56
$ awk '{ sub(/\r$/, ""); print }' file1 file2
1.234
2.345
11.567
7.890
12.11
0.00
4.56
2.34
```